# Showing default item using ComboEditorTool

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics

I've following code in my xaml.

```
<igRibbon:ComboEditorTool 
ItemsSource="{Binding MyProducts}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedProduct }" />
```

MyProducts is a collection having following values:

1. P1
2. P2
3. P3

In my ViewModel.cs constructor,I've

```
public string MySelectedProduct {get; set;}

MySelectedProduct = "P1";

public List<string> MyProducts {get; set;}

private GetProducts()
{

MyProducts.Add("P1");
MyProducts.Add("P2");
MyProducts.Add("P3");
}
```

But somehow this code is not working and I see the default item as blank in the combobox.(If I click on the combobox, then I see all 3 values.)

I did add OnPropertyChanged to MyProducts and MySelectedProduct but still no luck.
Please advise.

Comment: Show the source code for MySelectedProduct.

Answer (score 1):

`MySelectedProduct` and `MyProducts` should be a dependency property or a property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.